# Odd behavior of Golang type conversion

Tags: go, type-conversion, integer, bitwise-xor

For Golang code:

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a uint8 = 1
    var b uint8 = 1
    fmt.Printf("%T %v %b\n", uint32(a^b)-1, uint32(a^b)-1, uint32(a^b)-1)
    fmt.Printf("%T %v %b\n", uint32(uint8(0))-1, uint32(uint8(0))-1, uint32(uint8(0))-1)
}
```

**When I run the above code, what I expect to see is, for both**

`fmt.Printf("%T %v %b\n", uint32(a^b)-1, uint32(a^b)-1, uint32(a^b)-1)`

and

`fmt.Printf("%T %v %b\n", uint32(uint8(0))-1, uint32(uint8(0))-1, uint32(uint8(0))-1)`,

there should be `constant -1 overflows uint32` error.

**The actual execution result:**

`fmt.Printf("%T %v %b\n", uint32(a^b)-1, uint32(a^b)-1, uint32(a^b)-1)` executed successfully.

`fmt.Printf("%T %v %b\n", uint32(uint8(0))-1, uint32(uint8(0))-1, uint32(uint8(0))-1)` caused `constant -1 overflows uint32` error.

Could someone help explain this? Thanks!

Comment: The code of the 1st line deals with variables, wihich have [defined rules for overflow](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Integer_overflow) _at runtime_ while the second line deals purely with constants, and all calculations there are performed at compile time, using a [different set of rules](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constants); also see [this](https://blog.golang.org/constants).

Comment: …To say that in other words: integers at runtime can overflow, in defined way. Typed constants cannot overflow as it's checked by the compiler which evaluates [constant expressions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constant_expressions) in your code.